# AWSLOG for php log files

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have implemented awslogs for syslogs to push logs on cloud watch and is working fine.
but when I am trying to log PHP errors it watches the error but the time of the error is not accurate.

**My awslogs.config**

```
datetime_format = [%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S]
file = /var/log/dev.log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = {instance_id}
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = /var/log/dev.log
```

**dev.log**

```
[2022-06-09T12:27:51.280621+00:00] doctrine.INFO: Disconnecting [] []
[2022-06-09T12:27:51.280621+00:00] doctrine.INFO: Disconnecting [] []
```

**CLoud watch**

```
2022-06-28T13:04:55.279+02:00   [2022-06-09T12:26:51.280621+00:00] doctrine.INFO: Disconnecting [] []

2022-06-28T13:04:55.279+02:00   [2022-06-09T12:27:51.280621+00:00] doctrine.INFO: Disconnecting [] []
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my mistake was not implementing a proper **datetime_format**

%f was missing which is a floating number shown in logs.

It should be

```
datetime_format = [%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+00:00]
```